# pip in virtual environment is asking for username and password

Tags: python, pip, virtualenv

I am attempting to do a pip in an active virtual environment as such

```
pip install -i https://update.synapse-wireless.com/pypi snapconnect

Downloading/unpacking snapconnect
User for update.synapse-wireless.com: ?? 
Password:  ??
  Real name of requirement snapconnect is snapconnect
  Could not find any downloads that satisfy the requirement snapconnect
No distributions at all found for snapconnect
Storing complete log in /root/.pip/pip.log
```

Why is it asking me for a user name and password ? Which username and password does it expect ? I am currently ssh into the machine

Comment: Check `.pip/pip.log` file

Comment: can you try this ' sudo -H pip install snapconnect -i https://update.synapse-wireless.com/pypi/ '

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Going across the [Synapse-wireless forums](https://forums.synapse-wireless.com/showthread.php?t=5291) post, it says to:

1. Update your pip:

   ```
   pip install --upgrade pip
   ```
2. Install `snapconnect`:

   ```
   pip install --extra-index-url https://update.synapse-wireless.com/pypi snapconnect
   ```